# Construct equivalence classes for a relation R

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations, equivalence-relations

Define relation *R* as follows: *xRy* if *x* and *y* are bit strings with |*x*| >= 2 and |*y*| >= 2 such that *x* and *y* agree in their first two bits. Show that *R* is an equivalence relation. Construct the equivalence classes for *R*.

Reflexive? Let *x*=*y*. Then *xRx*, since *x* is a bit string with cardinality >= 2, and agrees in its own first two bits.

Symmetric? Yes, because the conditions are not dependent on order. If *xRy* then *yRx* just as well.

Transitive? Indeed; if *xRy* and *yRz*, then *x*, *y*, and *z* are all bit strings with cardinality >= 2 with the same first two bits. Therefore *xRz*.

But to construct the equivalence classes, I don't even know where to start =\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $R$ is an equivalence relation on the set $A$, the equivalence class of the element $a \in A$ is ${[a]}_{R} = \{s \, | \, a R s\}$. The set $A$ here is the set of all bit-strings of length $\geq 2$.

We can take $00$, $01$, $10$, and $11$ as representatives (why?), giving us the following equivalence classes:
$$
\begin{gather*}
{[00]}_{R} = \text{the set of all bit-strings which begin with }00 \\
{[01]}_{R} = \text{the set of all bit-strings which begin with }01 \\
{[10]}_{R} = \text{the set of all bit-strings which begin with }10 \\
{[11]}_{R} = \text{the set of all bit-strings which begin with }11
\end{gather*}
$$

Comment: Oh, too true! Thanks!